# HTTP POST Request Encryption

Tags: encryption, http

I have a client and a server that exchange information with each other and i want to encrypt the contents of the POST request? What kinds of encryption are supported by the HTTP Post request?

Thanks

Comment: Do some research on TLS.

Answer (score 7):

> What kinds of encryption are supported by the HTTP Post request?

None.  Encryption is implemented using TLS to wrap the entire HTTP layer, which is then called HTTPS.  The underlying HTTP methods and protocol remain unchanged.